ConTeXt: Center-aligned page number in footer at the start of Chapter or Title and right-aligned them in header elsewhere
I hope the question is self-explanatory. I typeset the page number using:
\setupindenting[yes, 1em]
\setuppagenumbering[location=header,alternative=singlesided,style=mediaeval]
\setupheadertexts[\hfill\userpagenumber]
\definestructureconversionset [frontpart:pagenumber] [] [romannumerals]
\startsectionblockenvironment[bodypart]
\setcounter[userpage][1]
\stopsectionblockenvironment

\starttext
\startchapter[title={This is Chapter or Title}]
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\stopchapter
\stoptext

I can remove the right-aligned page number (in header) at the start of Chapter using \setuphead[chapter][header=empty, footer=] but I do not know what to do to make the page number reappears in footer, e.g., what to fill footer= with.
Thanks heaps for any help and suggestion from ConTeXt magicians here.

Guided a bit by what Wolfgang showed on the mailing list last week, you can use \definetext,
\definetext
   [chapterfooter]
   [footer]
   [pagenumber]

\setuphead
   [chapter]
   [header=empty,
    footer=chapterfooter]

I also changed your \setupheadertexts
\setupheadertexts[] % <- reset the middle one
\setupheadertexts[][\userpagenumber] % <- set the right one

All-in-all:
\setupindenting[yes,1em]
\setuppagenumbering
  [location=header,
   alternative=singlesided,
   style=mediaeval]

% Not relevant for this example(?)
% \definestructureconversionset [frontpart:pagenumber] [] [romannumerals]
% \startsectionblockenvironment[bodypart]
% \setcounter[userpage][1]
% \stopsectionblockenvironment

%New/changed
\setupheadertexts[]
\setupheadertexts[][\userpagenumber]

\definetext
   [chapterfooter]
   [footer]
   [pagenumber]

\setuphead
   [chapter]
   [header=empty,
    footer=chapterfooter]
%End new

\starttext

\startchapter[title={This is Chapter or Title}]
  \dorecurse{20}{\samplefile{knuth}\par}
\stopchapter

\stoptext

The result from this file is (first few pages)


You can set the pagenumber for all non chapter pages with \setuppagenumbering[location={header,right}] or when you need more control disable the normal placement with \setuppagenumbering[location=] (this has the same effect as \setupheadertexts[]) and do the reset with \setupheadertexts.
